# Add animation to UILabel when the page is opened

Tags: swift, uilabel, uianimation

I read and watched many tutorial about adding animation to labels but none of them work for me as I wanted. 
I want when I open a view controller, after a second, a UILabel start to fade in from the bottom of the page and come to the center of the page.
for example here is the outlet of the label that I said about

```
  @IBOutlet weak var welcomeLabel: UILablel!
```

I made this function and add it to the `viewdidload` but it's not showing any animation, also when I tap on it will crash with this error:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

here is the function:

```
func addAnimation() {
    UILabel.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 3, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.welcomeLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -200)
    })
}
```

I also know this is not the animation that I wated, I just add it for the test. Could you help me to write the right animation that I wanted:

Start to fade in and move from the bottom to the center of the page.

thank you so much

Comment: The label isn't properly connected in your storyboard/xib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `@IBOutlet` of `UILabel` and put the label in the center of the screen and add the required `constraint`.

Create `@IBOutlet of label center Y alignment of Constraint` like below.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var centerY: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then change its constant value.

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        centerY.constant =  self.view.bounds.height/2
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        addAnimation()
    }

    func addAnimation(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
            self.centerY.constant = 0
            self.welcomeLabel.alpha = 1.0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your label is not connected on view controller now. Because of that you are getting that error.

After that, place label center of the screen and create centerY outlet of it. Now you can animate it with changing this centerY constant and fade it with changing alpha value.

For example:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3)  {
   self.centerY.constant = //your value
   self.label. alpha = 1
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```